# how to calculate $\sum_{x=1}^\infty xq^{2x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Its been a long time since I last dealt with series's like this: $\sum_{x=1}^\infty xq^{2x}$, I tried to take to a form where I can calculate the derivative of other sum, but didn't work. I'd be happy if someone shows the way.

Note: $|q|<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$y\cdot\frac d{dy}\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty ny^n$$

Let $y=q^2$ and apply the geometric series.

Comment: This is the way I would have proceeded, but since you beat me to it, I posted a solution that uses another way forward.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV I suppose if anyone's interested, a third way could be the binomial theorem ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on elementary tools and not on differentiation of a series.

Using $x=\sum_{y=1}^x (1)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=1}^\infty xq^{2x}&=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^x q^{2x}\\\\
&=\sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{x=y}^\infty  q^{2x}\\\\
&=\sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{q^{2y}}{1-q^2}\\\\
&=\frac{q^2}{(1-q^2)^2}
\end{align}$$

> **Tools Used:**  Interchanging order of summation (Fubini) and Summing Geometric Series.